# reposman.rb fails querying projects : "invalid character at <?xml"

Tags: redmine, xml

I try to update the projects to the SVN repos using reposman, here is the command I use :

```
ruby /home/redmine/redmine-1.2.1/extra/svn/reposman.rb --redmine redmine.mywebsite.com --svn-dir /var/svn --owner redmine --group www-data --url http://svn.mywebsite.com --key=myapikey --verbose
```

And here is the result I got from reposman.rb :

```
querying Redmine for projects...
Unable to connect to http://redmine.mywebsite.com/sys/: invalid character at "<?xml vers"
```

When I look at the production.log, here is what I have :

```
Processing SysController#projects to json (for 91.121.201.65 at 2011-09-05 14:31:50) [GET]
  Parameters: {"key"=>"myapikey"}
Completed in 40ms (View: 1, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://redmine.myewebsite.com/sys/projects.json?key=myapikey]
```

But when I go to the http://redmine.myewebsite.com/sys/projects.json?key=myapikey url, I have a correct xml page with a list of my projects.

What is wrong? (Please ask me what I have to show you more from my server to help you.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and this was the only promising looking search result.

My problem was, that I was using a wrong version of the active record gem. I had version 3.1.0 installed. But with version 2.3.11 it works fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: I add to remove more than juste activerecord -v=3.1.0 (activesupport, actionmailer, etc (but just for 3.1.0)). But then, it worked. I removed many gems before trying again so I don't know which one was the core of the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded activerecord 3.1.0 to activerecord 2.3.11, but still had the problem.  Like ServiusHack, mentioned.  Downgrading activeresource from 3.1.0 to 2.3.11 did the trick for me.

Thanks for the advice guys!

---